# Create object to append to both HTTP and HTTPS Express Servers in Node.js

Tags: node.js, express

Ok, so I have a node.js app with two express servers.  One that listens on port 80 (HTTP) and one that on port 443 (HTTPS).

Now, these do NOT have all the same routes.  Quite the contrary, most things are served over HTTPS with some over HTTP.  But, there is some overlap.

So, I am wondering is there a way to 'bind' routes to both secureApp and App as I call them such that I don't have to write the route twice?

ex. Right now I have two sets of the same route (one for HTTP and one for HTTPS):

```
app.get('/tweet-stats.json', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(publicTweetStatus());
});

secureApp.get('/tweet-stats.json', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(publicTweetStatus());
});
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
model.get('/tweet-stats.json', function(req, res){
    res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    res.send(publicTweetStatus());
});

app.handle.bind(model);
secureApp.handle.bind(model);
```

Is this possible?  I would make for much better coding where I only manage ONE instance of this particular route across all ports.

Comment: I'm genuinely curious, why wouldn't you serve everything over HTTPS?

Comment: Performance.  Only certain things are truly private data.  That requires HTTPS, everything else is public and I will serve over HTTP or HTTPS (users choice).  Some users like HTTPS all the time and use browser plugins like [HTTP Everywhere](https://www.eff.org/https-everywhere). I will never downgrade an HTTPS request, but I will require the extra security for anything private.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

why are you repeating yourself? just block routes that can't be used

```
function secureOnly(req, res, next) {
  if (!req.secure) {
    res.send(426, 'sorry')
  else {
    next()
  }
}
```

and listen on two ports

```
http.createServer(app).listen(80)
https.createServer(app).listen(443)
```

Comment: ...and in secure-only routes, specify thusly: `app.get('/route', secureOnly, function(req, res) { ... });`

Comment: Really interesting idea.  But, wouldn't I want to use a 301 redirect? [See here](http://serverfault.com/questions/289697/should-i-use-http-code-301-or-426-on-port-80-of-a-https-only-server)

Comment: Up to you. Point is, no need to repeat yourself!